# How to add animation to menu

Tags: css

I have a simple design here
just I want to make animation when menu open and close like moving from left to right when open and left to right when it close
here is my link to watch codes in Code open
https://codepen.io/Ahmed-Saif-the-solid/pen/eYoRrwe

and here my codes
this is HTML

```
<body>
<div class="header">
      <a href="" id="MenueIcon" class="MenueIcon">
      menue
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="sub_container">
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
          <div id="closeMenueIcon" class="closeMenueIcon">
          X
        </div>
</div>
    <div id="white_backcolor" class="white_backcolor">
      <div id="content_space"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

this is style code

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
}

.header{  
display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: center;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sub_container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap; flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
 
}


.white_backcolor {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap; flex-grow: 15;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#content_space {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

/* hide side_parent if screen < 750 */
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}


.sidebar_Media_Show {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: var(--transition);
}


.closeMenueIcon {
  display: none;
  height: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.2rem 0 0 0.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.closeMenueIcon:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .closeMenueIcon {
    display: block;
  }

  .closeMenueIcon i {
    color: red;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

here javascript code

```
const sidebar =  document.querySelector('#sidebar');
const MenueIcon = document.querySelector('#MenueIcon');
const closeMenueIcon = document.querySelector('#closeMenueIcon');

// hide and show menu when click 
MenueIcon.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop a deafult herf 
        const sidebar_status =  sidebar.classList.contains("sidebar_Media_Show"); // check if sidbar have this class or no
        if(sidebar_status){
            sidebar.classList.remove("sidebar_Media_Show"); 
        }else{
            sidebar.classList.add("sidebar_Media_Show"); 
        }  
})

// auto close menu when resizing screen > 750px
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if (window.innerWidth > 750) {
        sidebar.classList.remove("sidebar_Media_Show"); 
      }
});
// hide menu when click X button
closeMenueIcon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    sidebar.classList.remove("sidebar_Media_Show"); 
})
```

i will be glade if you show me how to make animation like transition when menu open and close

Answer (score 0):

There are of course many ways but the most common one is adding a CSS class that holds a different property than without it, while utilizing `transition` property.

```css
.myclass {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.myclass:hover {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50px, 20px);
  opacity: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  hover me
</div>
```